# Where to place Toasts, Snackbars etc. in era of Android Architecture Components

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

What is the recommendation about placing Toasts, Snackbars in Activity vs. Fragment in the era of `ViewModel` and `one activity multiple fragments` concept.

Its clear that things like

- new Intents
- Fragment transactions/fragment setup
- permission requests
- presenting navigational components (drawer, viewpager)

should be handled by activity but what about **Toasts**/**Snackbars**?

There are so many SO questions about how to show Toasts or Snackbars in Fragment and how + when to use `getContext()` that I tend to let the activity handle all showing messages.

With ViewModel and [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) its quite easy to have a sharedViewModel that will be observed by activity and fragments and when needed a fragment dispatchs an event that notifies the activity to show a message.

So what do you think is best practice/recommended while having resposibility and separation of concerns in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a cue from [Google's codelabs on basic architecture components](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#13), it seems better to let fragments/activities react to changes in `ViewModel`.

From the Google link above, it thus means that one of the most efficient methods is to `Observe()` a `LiveData` property of a `ViewModel` object from your `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

it depends. Probably you can always replace toasts/snackbars with some UI parts (TextViews, Buttons) or Dialogs / DialogFragments.

it really depends on your app architecture, but I guess you can design some dependency: activity- or fragment-scoped, so you can inject it as abstraction for your ViewModel and use like you want.

IMHO if you deal with Toasts, you can design MessageShower at activty/application scope and reuse it everywhere(dealing with single instance of toast), but Snackbars needs View to be shown(so they need lifecycle, and it is more easier to make memory leak).

```
interface MessageShower{
    void showMessage(String message);
}

class LongToastMessageShower implements MessageShower{
    private Toast toast;

    public LongToastMessageShower(Context appContext){
         this.toast = Toast.makeText(appContext,"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    @Override
    public void showMessage(String message){
        toast.cancel();
        toast.setText(message);
        toast.show(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `BaseActivity` and `BaseFragment` where you create all common methods like Toast, Snackbar etc which is extended in `YourActivity` and `YourFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

use AndroidViewModel()
e.g

```
class LoginViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
     private val context = getApplication<Application>().applicationContext
     //use that context when toasting in your viewModel
}
```

for snackbar
if its a button in your xml use this attribute and value

```
android:onClick="@{() -> login.signIn(signIn)}"
```

signIn inside the brackets in that context refers to the id of your button on which you are setting the onClick attribute
Remember that login before .signIn refers to your variable name

In your viewModel

```
fun signIn(view: View){
   //use view to display your snack bar
}
```